# ASP Sending E-mail with CDOSYS and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, email, asp-classic

I try to send an Email by using CDOSYS and AJAX in IIS 7 Server.
I have sent an AJAX request to send the mail. And AJAX returns 200 OK status.
But the Email was not arrived.
Who can solve my problem? Thanks a lot!

**I have 3 files:**

**1. index.html**
[image]

**2. main.js**

```
    function sendEmailAjaxFunc(){

        var cusName = document.getElementById("cusName").value;
        var emailAdr = document.getElementById("emailAdr").value;

        var xmlhttp;
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","sendEmail.asp?cusName="+cusName+"&emailAdr="+emailAdr+"&sTime="+new Date().getTime(),true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                //finish report
                //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        return true;
    }
```

**3. sendEmail.asp**

```
    <%@ Language=JScript CodePage=65001 %>
    <%

        var cusName = Request.QueryString("cusName");
        var emailAdr = Request.QueryString("emailAdr");

        var objMail = Server.CreateObject( "CDO.Message" );
        objMail.BodyPart.charset = "unicode-1-1-utf-8";
        objMail.From = 'info@it.com';
        objMail.To = emailAdr;
        objMail.Cc = emailAdr;
        objMail.Subject = 'It-Zhai GmbH';
        objMail.TextBody = 'Hello ' + cusName + ', just a text email';
        //objMail.HTMLBody = 'HTML';
        //objMail.AddAttachment('justAttachment.txt');
        objMail.SendMail;
    %>
```

Comment: Have you tried requesting sendmail.asp directly in your browser with the parameters in a querystring?  You might get an error message which will help yoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an email server set up to send the message? It looks like you need to configure the message to be sent through a server.

Here are a few more options to add to your configuration...

```
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server'

objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.myserver.com"

'Server port (typically 25)'

objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

objMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
```

You can find more info here... http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

Comment: Thank you! :) This Configuration is necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks buddies!

I have found a solution. 
An email was finally sent from my Server. 
In the file sendEmail.asp I should do this configuration:

```
    var oServer=new ActiveXObject("CDO.Configuration");
    oServer.Fields(cdoSMTPServer)="...";  //Server Adresse
    oServer.Fields(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = 1;
    oServer.Fields(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = 1;
    oServer.Fields(cdoSendUsername)="...";
    oServer.Fields(cdoSendPassword)="...";
```